# Remove upload tab from Link menu

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to remove the "Upload" tab when using the Link dialog? I don't need it removed globally, just in the Link functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`config.dialogRemoveTabs`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeDialogTabs):

```
config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:upload';
```